# Parse if else statement using Compiler Tree API

Tags: java, netbeans, abstract-syntax-tree, netbeans-platform

I am trying to find a way to parse java code source in netbeans using the Tree API, I learned through this [guide](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Java_DevelopersGuide%22guide%22) how I can access high level language elements (classes,methods,fields ..).

what I'm looking for is a way to parse if else statements (for a start) since I'm trying to apply *replace type code with state strategy* refactoring afterwards. it is very important for me to get the if condition. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: seriously, why the downvote? should I edit the question somehow? I really need any answer or advice ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After diving into the Compiler Tree API doc I found how to access low level code the condition of a selected if statement in my case, here is a code snippet

```
  @Override
    public Void visitIf(IfTree node, Void p) {
        try {
            JTextComponent editor = EditorRegistry.lastFocusedComponent();
            if (editor.getDocument() == info.getDocument()) {
                InputOutput io = IOProvider.getDefault().getIO("Analysis of " + info.getFileObject().getName(),
                        true);
                ExpressionTree exTree = node.getCondition();
                if (exTree.getKind() == Tree.Kind.PARENTHESIZED) {
                    ParenthesizedTree parTree = (ParenthesizedTree) exTree;
                    BinaryTree conditionTree = (BinaryTree) parTree.getExpression();
                    ExpressionTree identTree = conditionTree.getLeftOperand();
                    if (identTree.getKind() == Tree.Kind.IDENTIFIER) {
                        Name name = ((IdentifierTree) identTree).getName();
                        io.getOut().println("Hurray, this is the name of the identifier in the left operand: " + name.toString());
                    }


           io.getOut().close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
            }
            return null;        
}
```

Thankfully the code naming is intuitive otherwise the documentation doesn't help much. debugging using println is very useful to know what kind of tree to deal with next.